# The difference between Int and Unwrapped Int

Tags: swift

I couldn’t find this anywhere on the web but when declaring class properties, I saw this version of implementation:

var _number: Int!

When I tried to remove the (!) I saw no difference. 
When declaring a class property, or in general, what is the difference between ClassName! And ClassName (without the !)? What is the meaning of adding the (!)?

Thank you!

Comment: Find a book about Swift and search for "optionals".

Comment: ! tell force unwrap. its all about optional.

Comment: Yeah I know what optionals are, but what does it mean when being made on a class property?